# I want the sentence (number of IRS Elements to be fit inside the cell)

Tags: tables, columns, size, cell

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &\multicolumn{11}{|c|}{Number of Users  / Number of Active Users} \\
     \cline{2-12}
  \multirow{10}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Number of IRS Elements}}  & N = 36 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\cline{2-12}    
  & N = 49 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\cline{2-12}
  & N = 64 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\cline{2-12}
  & N = 81 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ \cline{2-12}
  & N = 100 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ 
   \hline  
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{The new one}
  \label{table}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2):

The size of the phrase is about equal to the table height, actually exceeding it by some points.

It fits with `\arraystretch` set to `1.7`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}

\begin{tabular}{|*{12}{c|}}
\hline
&\multicolumn{11}{|c|}{Number of Users  / Number of Active Users} \\
\cline{2-12}
  & N = 36 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\cline{2-12}    
  & N = 49 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\cline{2-12}
  & N = 64 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\cline{2-12}
  & N = 81 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ \cline{2-12}
\smash{\rotatebox{90}{Number of IRS Elements}}
  & N = 100 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ 
\hline  
\end{tabular}

\caption{The new one}
\label{table}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

With `\smash` I tell LaTeX that the rotated box has actually no height.

[image]

However, I'd not understand what that column refers to.

Comment: the column N is the Number of IRS Elements

Comment: @AlexDirc The other columns lack an explanatory header.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done using the `\makecell` command from the `makecell` package if you don't want to change the vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{12}{c|}}
    \hline
    \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\makecell[c]{Number of IRS\\ Elements}}}   &\multicolumn{11}{|c|}{Number of Users  / Number of Active Users} \\
     \cline{2-12}
   & N = 36 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\cline{2-12}    
  & N = 49 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\cline{2-12}
  & N = 64 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\cline{2-12}
  & N = 81 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ \cline{2-12}
  & N = 100 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ 
   \hline  
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{The new one}
  \label{table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

**Edit according to the comment of the OP:**

Just use the "Number of IRS Elements" as the header of the column containing values of "N". Also, you can use the `\thead` command from the `makecell` package to insert any linebreak if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{11}{c|}}
    \hline
    \thead{Number of IRS\\ Elements}   &\multicolumn{10}{|c|}{Number of Users  / Number of Active Users} \\
    \hline
    N = 36 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\hline    
    N = 49 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\hline
    N = 64 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\hline
    N = 81 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ \hline
    N = 100 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ 
    \hline  
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{The new one}
  \label{table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: second table]

**Edit 2:** Improvement according to the comments of @leandriis. I have also made some changes in the first column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}
  %\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
  
  \begin{tabular}{|*{11}{c|}}
    \hline
    \thead{Number of IRS\\ Elements, N}   &\multicolumn{10}{c|}{\thead{Number of Users  / Number of Active Users}} \\
    \hline
    36 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\hline    
    49 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\hline
    64 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\hline
    81 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ \hline
    100 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ 
    \hline  
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{The new one}
  \label{table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: leandriis Table]

Comment: the problem is the first two columns the Number of IRS elements and N=!, should be together in one column

Comment: @AlexDirc Sorry, I can't understand your comment clearly. Do  you want to merge the first two columns into one?

Comment: yes I want to do that

Comment: Do you want something like this https://imgur.com/a/CSQ7NcW

Comment: yes that is perfect

Comment: @Imran: Some minor comments to your second suggestion: You may want to use `\multicolumn{10}{c|}` instead of `\multicolumn{10}{|c|}` in order to avoid the thicker vertical line inbetween the two column headers. Currently, the table is slightly wider than the textwidth. In order to avoid that, you could add `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5ptpt}` before the `tabular` environment or use `tabular*` in combination with `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}. [...]

Comment: [...] Lastly, the column headers use a different font size. To overcome this, either use `\thead{Number of Users  / Number of Active Users}` (to also decrease the font size of the second column header) or add `\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}` inside of `table`, but before `tabular` (to increase the font size of the first column header). You may in this case also want to use `\thead{Number of\\ IRS Elements}` instead of `\thead{Number of IRS\\ Elements}`.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks a lot. I love the way people help one another in this site.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{*{11}{c}}[hvlines]
    \Block{}{Number of IRS\\ Elements, N}   
       &\Block{1-*}{Number of Users  / Number of Active Users} \\
    36 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\    
    49 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\
    64 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\
    81 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ 
    100 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ 
  \end{NiceTabular}
  \caption{The new one}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{*{12}{c}}[hvlines]
       &\Block{1-*}{Number of Users  / Number of Active Users} \\
    \Block{*-1}<\rotate>{Number of IRS\\ Elements, N}   
    & 36 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\    
    & 49 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\
    & 64 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\
    & 81 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ 
    & 100 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ 
  \end{NiceTabular}
  \caption{The new one}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{*{12}{c}}[hvlines,corners]
       &\Block{1-*}{Number of Users  / Number of Active Users} \\
    \Block{*-1}<\rotate>{Number of IRS\\ Elements, N}   
    & 36 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\    
    & 49 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\
    & 64 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\
    & 81 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ 
    & 100 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ 
  \end{NiceTabular}
  \caption{The new one}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

I propose to split the sentence in twolines, with  `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx} 
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|wc{8mm}|*{11}{c|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{} &\multicolumn{11}{|c|}{Number of Users / Number of Active Users} \\
 \cline{2-12}
& N = 36 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\cline{2-12}
& N = 49 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\cline{2-12}
& N = 64 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\\cline{2-12}
& N = 81 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\ \cline{2-12}
\multirow{-5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\Centerstack{Number of\\ IRS Elements}}} & N = 100 & 1/2 & 2/2 & 3/2 & 4/2 & 5/2 & 6/2 & 7/2 & 8/2 & 9/2 & 10/2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The new one}
\label{table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]